# What are the birthdays of the four waitresses + Hideri?

Tags: blend-s

I am trying to determine the birthdays of **Maika**, **Kaho**, **Mafuyu**, **Miu**, and **Hideri** of *Blend S.*  As far as I know, the birthday of Maika is [April 4th](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55825/when-is-maika-sakuranomiyas-birthday).

Can someone list the birthdays of the four waitresses and Hideri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Birthdays are:

- Sakuranomiya **Maika** (April 4.) Age 16
- Hinata **Kaho** (August 12.) Age 17
- Hoshikawa **Mafuyu** (December 23.) Age 20
- Amano **Miu** (June 9.) Age 22
- Kanzaki **Hideri** (July 10) Age 16

Source: https://blend-s.fandom.com/wiki/Characters

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀